# Should I use the singular or plural verb form with "one or more"?

Tags: verb-agreement

Which of these is correct?

> "If one or more of these situations apply to you ..."
>   or
>   "If one or more of these situations applies to you ..."

I think that "more" takes precedence over "one," so I would use the plural, "apply." Am I right?

Comment: There's no good rule for [Sg *or* Pl] subject agreement, as you can tell. What most people do is (a) avoid the construction if possible, or (b) put the singular one as far away from the verb as possible, putting in some irrelevant stuff afterwards if possible. Then, quickly, put the plural one at the end, follow it immediately with a plural verb, and go on fast after that. Nobody will notice.

Comment: A secondary consideration is that using the plural verb covers the case of one, sort of. The singular does not work for both. Here: If offered cookies when I want only one, would I say "No, I do not want *cookies*. I want one cookie." Realizing I used nouns, I suggest that if zero and two cookies are good, and one *is* good, then one cookie *are* not to be sneered at.

Comment: @Yosef Baskin I'd use 'Can I just have one, please.' (I don't see it as a true question, but as a hedged request.) But would you use 'One and a half cookies are ...'? '1.02 cookies are ...'? '1.0 cookies are ...'? (the last intended as a rounded rather than a precise figure)